# rhel7 yum repolist error

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

Since I Ctrl-C during `yum install xxx` on my RHEL7

```
^Chttps://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#56 - "Callback aborted"
Trying other mirror.
```

I got the following error. How to fix it?

```
$ yum repolist
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Repo rhel-7-server-rpms forced skip_if_unavailable=True due to: /etc/pki/entitlement/6004208575190148944-key.pem
https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#58 - "unable to load client key: -8178 (SEC_ERROR_BAD_KEY)"
Trying other mirror.
```

`yum clean all` doesn't help

Comment: Does an `ls -l` on the key file show a non-zero size?

Comment: Yes, ```ls -l /etc/pki/entitlement/6004208575190148944-key.pem
-rw-------. 1 root root 1675 Dec 15 01:21 /etc/pki/entitlement/6004208575190148944-key.pem```

Answer (score 4):

Based only on your shell prompt being `$` and not `#`, I assume that you are running the command as a non-root user, and are thus unable to read the entitlement key at `/etc/pki/entitlement/6004208575190148944-key.pem`, which on my default RHEL7 system, have permissions:

```
-rw-------. 1 root root ...
```

The quick solution is to prefix your command with `sudo`, or to log in as root before running the command. I presume you have permissions, based on your earlier attempt to perform a `yum install`.

Comment: Same result with #yum install xxx as root (or #yum repolist) . I must have broken some repo when I used Ctrl-C and now don't know how to fix it.